# How do you do "remember me" functionality in AngularJS?

Tags: security, authentication, angularjs

I have a [simple app I'm building](https://github.com/lightbody/roadmapper) using Play + AngularJS that requires authentication before most routes can be accessed. The login flow includes a "remember me" feature that stores a session ID in to the browser local storage and gets mapped to a valid authorized database session entry on the server side any time a user returns to the app.

The problem I'm having is that I do the session checking (extract cookie & compare against server) in the [run() function](https://github.com/lightbody/roadmapper/blob/master/public/js/roadmapper.js#L157) of the module:

```
    .run(function ($rootScope, $http, $cookieStore, $location) {
        // <snip>

        // check if there is already a session?
        var sessionId = window.localStorage["session.id"];
        if (sessionId == null) {
            sessionId = $cookieStore.get("session.id");
        }

        if (sessionId != null) {
            $http.get("/sessions/" + sessionId)
                .success(function (data) {
                    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Session-ID'] = data.id;
                    $cookieStore.put("session.id", data.id);

                    $rootScope.user = data.user;
                })
                .error(function () {
                    // remove the cookie, since it's dead
                    $cookieStore.remove("session.id");
                    window.localStorage.removeItem("session.id");
                    $location.path("/login");
                });
        } else {
            if ($location.path() != "/login" && $location.path() != "/signup") {
                $location.path("/login");
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that this function executes an AJAX call and I don't know if the session is valid until it completes. However, the controller that loads (via the route selected by $routeProvider) can fire away another AJAX call that often kicks off before the other one finishes, resulting in a race condition and the initial request getting a 401 response code.

So my question is: how can I force run (with its associated $http call) to complete before any other part of the app runs? I have tried using $q/promise here and it doesn't seem to make a difference (perhaps run functions don't honor promises). I've been advisor to use `resolve` feature in [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider) but I don't know exactly what to do and I'm not super execited about having to put that in for every route anyway.

I assume this is a pretty common use case and it gets solved every day. Hopefully someone can give me some direction with my code, or share their approaches for "remember me" and AngularJS.

Comment: so you want to check the session on every route change?

Comment: No, just on the initialization of the app. That's where the race condition is killing me.

Comment: if you have to just use on init of app why dont u put the code in resolve function of the init route  controller of app

Comment: Ajay -- I'm not sure what you'r suggesting. Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth

Comment: Update: I never figured this out, so the best I have done so far is to assume the session ID is valid and set it right away for future HTTP requests. Then I will still check the session ID and if it turns out it's invalid, I invalid the local storage and open the login prompt. It works well enough, but I'd love to know how to block the app from running until the session verification completed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manual bootstrap your app after you get session from server.It's easy if you use jQuery for example you can do, or even without jQuery you can use injector to access $http before bootstrapping

```
$.get(server,function(){ 
//success , set variable.
}).fail(function (){ 
//failed :( redirect to login or set session to false etc... null
})
.always(function(){
//alwyas bootstrap in both case and set result as a constant or variable Angular.module('app').variable('session',sessionResult);
});
```

I'm on phone right now, but this should give u the idea